# Undefined method in Rails console when adding role to user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-console

I am trying to add a role to a specific user in my Rails Console via Heroku , but I am getting the error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `role=' for # .

If you take a look at the screenshot below the role you can see all of the columns in the User table that is available:

[image: user_columns]

The command I am using from the rails console is below to assign the role to the user. I saw a similar post on StackOverflow about the same error but after the db migrate I still got the same error.  Can someone point me in the right direction possibly?

[image]

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
 # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
     :confirmable
has_many :posts

def admin?
role == 'admin'
end

 def moderator?
 role == 'moderator'
 end


 end
```

Comment: You don't have a single `User` record.  You have an `ActiveRecord::Relation`.  Try doing `u = u.first` and try `u.role = 'admin'` again.

Comment: Remember to read the logs *carefully*.